# Is there a menubar similar to p:menubar that is accessible?

Tags: primefaces, accessibility, menubar, wcag

The current menubar I am using has the same format as the one found on the Primefaces showcase. For example:

```
<h:form>  
<p:growl id="messages"/>

<p:menubar>
    <p:submenu label="File" icon="ui-icon-document">
        <p:submenu label="New" icon="ui-icon-contact">
            <p:menuitem value="Project" url="#" />
            <p:menuitem value="Other" url="#" />
        </p:submenu>
        <p:menuitem value="Open" url="#" />
        <p:separator />
        <p:menuitem value="Quit" url="#" />
    </p:submenu>       
</p:menubar>
```

I am trying to be AODA compliant and I wish for my menubar to be accessible. I have found a work-around to make it work from the keyboard. The issue is when tabbing through the menu using a screen reader like JAWS it does not read any of the menu elements. Does anyone know an alternative menubar I can use that is similar in appearance to Primefaces menubar but correctly interacts with a screen reader (ie all the menu elements are read)? I am using Primefaces 5.2.

Comment: Would a jQuery module be good enough?

Comment: Would that help a screen reader read the contents of the menubar? I don't have experience with jQuery so I am unaware it is an appropriate solution.

Comment: it is probably not appropriate then. Here is the link https://github.com/dylanb/a11yfy/blob/master/a11yfy.md#menu

Comment: Here is an example (not very well styled) http://dylanb.github.io/bower_components/a11yfy/examples/menu.html

Comment: I tried your example with JAWS. It has some issues but is an improvement from what I have. I will play around with it and see what I can do. Thanks!

Comment: What are the issues you have with the PF menubar? The source is opeb and easily changable

Comment: Yes. Could you point me in the right direction on how to do so? I'm unfamiliar with the process